# is there an ability to rewind a number of frames in a VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

Under a certain condition, I need to be able to rewind a video by 10 frames. 
So far, I have a `VideoCapture cap` from which I extract frames for edit and display with `cap >> frame` where `frame` is of type `Mat` (which is what all my remaining frame edits are built on.

I found that you can rewind frames with

```
int cvSetCaptureProperty( CvCapture* capture, int property_id, double value );
```

but the problem is, that this is not compatible with my `VideoCapture cap`, the compiler says:

```
min.cpp:158:72: error: cannot convert ‘cv::VideoCapture’ to ‘CvCapture*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int cvSetCaptureProperty(CvCapture*, int, double)’
             cvSetCaptureProperty(cap,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, i-TRCK_MRG);
                                                                        ^
min.cpp:159:37: error: cannot convert ‘cv::VideoCapture’ to ‘CvCapture*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘IplImage* cvQueryFrame(CvCapture*)’
             frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);
```

and if I use `VideoCapture *cap`, to capture frames as `IplImage*  frame`, the remainder of my program needs to be modified too unless I convert frames back into a `Mat` type.

Hence, is there an ability to rewind a number of frames in a `VideoCapture`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cvSetCaptureProperty` and `CvCapture` and `IplImage` is from the C interface which is deprecated and should not be used unless it is strictly necessary.

However you can use the same function with the C++ interface, to be more precise is [this one](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set). The code would looks something like:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("moviefile.mp4");

// read 200 frames
for (int i =0; i < 200; ++i)
 cap.read();

// get the current position
auto pos = cap.get(cv::CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
// set the new position
cap.set(cv::CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos-10);
```

I have not tried this yet, but I think is your best shot. With a live camera instead of a file, I doubt that it will work at all.